# react-redux dispatch an action that depends on another synchronously

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to update the store using redux actions. I need to dispatch two actions to get my result. Note that I don't have control over the `setFieldAction` so it has to be done in two actions. Now when I call the second dispatch I am getting an error since the first one is not yet completed, i.e the state is not updated until the next render. So How can I accomplish that?

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setFieldAction(0, "field1", "value1"));
    dispatch(setFieldAction(0, "field2", "value2"));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect changes in the FieldAction state in a useEffect function and apply checks on it. for example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(props.reducer?.obj1?.obj2?.FieldAction === "something"){ // check the value and dispatch the appropriate action,  for example
       dispatch(setFieldAction(0, "field2", "value2"));
    }
}, [props.reducer?.obj1]); // this will be called whenever props.reducer.obj1 is updated
```

Comment: But FieldAction is in the reducer such as props.reducer.obj1.obj2.FieldAction. and obj1 can be undefined and so is obj2

Comment: Then you can look for changes in that object. I'm updating my answer

Comment: yes but obj1 can be undefined and so is obj2

Comment: You can apply checks for that as well, like:  props.reducer?.obj1. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: https://redux-saga.js.org/

It can let you run your actions asynchronously, so you can await the change you need and then complete your action with the result you want. You can also set it up to see if an action was successful or if it has failed.

There's a bunch of good tutorials on it on YouTube if you're curious on how it works.

Comment: Thanks! But that is not what I want.